# How to retrieve selected nodes from firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

This is how my `firebase` database looks like.

[image]

I want to access the node `accepting-status` and say `patient23` for example. I can easily do this by using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` on nodes `accepting-status` and `patient23` separately but then it would take me two different requests to get the required data. I can also get the required data by single request by adding `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` on the parent node `beacon-final` but then that would retrieve huge data because the patients are in large numbers.How do I do it in a single request and yet only retrieve only the required nodes. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...but then it would take me two different requests to get the
>   required data.

The Firebase database is all one JSON object. If you select one part, you'll get everything underneath.

But, Firebase uses WebSockets, which is a persistent connection to the server. [This means that you don't have to worry about making a request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers#Client_Handshake_Request), because the only HTTP request that gets made is in the very beginning to establish the socket.

So in your case it's completely feasible to make two separate "requests" for the data, because there's no real overhead to consider. The device's radio is already on, and a WebSocket header is merely 6 bytes.

You can easily create a listener on `/accepting-status`, as well as `/patients/patient23`. This is a standard Firebase practice to have multiple listeners.

```
// Get a root reference 
Firebase rootRef = new Firebase("<my-firebase-app>");
// accepting-status ref
Firebase statusRef = rootRef.child("accepting-status");
// patient23 ref
Firebase patientRef = rootRef.child("patients").child("patient23");

// Listen for status updates
statusRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        System.out.println(snapshot.getValue());
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        // error
    }
});

// Listen for patient updates
patientRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        System.out.println(snapshot.getValue());
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        // error
    }
});
```

Comment: "the only HTTP request that gets made is in the very beginning to establish the socket" can you please tell when exactly is the HTTP request is made?

Comment: When the application first tries to connect to the Firebase database. This is apart of the WebSocket protocol. So essentially there is only one HTTP request ever made, and it's from the client to establish the WebSocket connection. "Read this article on the WebSocket protocol for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers#Client_Handshake_Request)

Comment: Ok. From the above code how can I know whether `snapshot` has data about the `statusRef` or the `patientRef` as both `statusRef` and `patientRef`  implemented the same listener?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do, but you can create two separate listeners. I only put them as one for the sake of brevity. I'll update to clarify.

Comment: You say  there is only one HTTP request ever made if this is true then how the change of data in the firebase database is detected by the app which is connected to it?

Comment: A WebSocket is a different protocol than HTTP. HTTP is request/response, when a connection responds, it then is closes. Whereas a WebSocket is a persistent connection, when data returns from the server the socket doesn't close.

Comment: Ok i get it!  So if I get data from the root node of my firebase database then it would have no extra overhead compared to if I get data from `accepting-status` which consists of only one integer value?

Comment: If you get data from the root node it will download every thing. So you can drill into `accepting-status` from the root node, and only retrieve that item. Then you can also retrieve only `patient23`, by going to the `/patients/patient23` node from the root. Make sense?

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know...this discussion was very enlightening. Thank you very much.